# trying to use web3.py but no methods seem to work

Tags: python, ethereum, web3py

trying to use web3.py V5.31.1 with infura as a websocketprovider, but no methods seem to work.

The only method that works is w3.eth.chainId

my code:

```
from web3 import Web3
import web3

w3 = Web3(Web3.WebsocketProvider('wss://mainnet.infura.io/ws/v3/myapikey'))

print(w3.eth.chainId)

#w3.clientVersion --#doesnt work
#w3.is_connected() --#doesnt work

try:
print(web3.eth.get_block('latest'))
except:
print(web3.eth.getBlock('latest'))
```

error:

```
AttributeError: module 'web3.eth' has no attribute 'getBlock'
AttributeError: module 'web3.eth' has no attribute 'get_block'
```

any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are confusing `w3` instance and `web3` module.

Please use:

```
print(w3.eth.get_block('latest'))
```

Comment: I suggest you take generic Python programming tutorials before trying to attempt anything as complex as blockchains. You need to understand the basic programming concepts like variables, classes and modules, because otherwise you need to ask help on every non-issue. Start here https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html